# postfix pipe mail to script does not work

Tags: bash, email, sh, postfix-mta

I've done my research and tried lots of way but to no avail, i still could not get my postfix mail to run the script.

**content of /etc/aliases**

```
test2: "|/home/testscript.sh"
```

**content of /home/testscript.sh Note: i've tried many kind of ways in the script. even a simple echo does not work.**

```
#!/bin/sh
read msg
echo $MSG
```

i've tried running the script and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So would you tell that it's working?

Even if you successfully direct mail to the script, you're not going to see the output of the "echo" command.  If you expect to get an email response from the script, the script will need to call out to `/bin/mail` (or `sendmail` or contact an SMTP server or something) to generate the message.  If you're just looking to verify that it's working, you need to create some output where you can see it -- for example, by writing the message to the filesystem:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat > /tmp/msg
```

You should also look in your mail logs (often but not necessarily `/var/log/mail`) to see if there are any errors (or indications of success!).

Comment: Hi there thanks for the reply! i've tried the above and no it does not work. yes i did verify many times and i did recieve the mail. :(

Comment: is there any chance that if i do not see /bin/mail in my directory, then it is the cause of my problems?

Comment: I don't see any evidence in your example that you're trying to use `/bin/mail`, so no, that would not seem to be relevant to your problems.  I suggest you check your mail logs first.

Comment: it says a warning of having aliases.db is old compared to aliases. Could it be it? how do i update the aliases.db file?

Comment: Awesome, glad to have helped!